# Tornado. Django-like testrunner and test database

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tornado

I like django unit tests, cause they create and drop test database on run.

What ways to create test database for tornado exists?

**UPD:** I'm interested in postgresql test database creation on test run.

Comment: Because Tornado doesn't tie you to a specific database, you may get a better response to this question if you refer to the specific database you're using.  I.e., I use a test rig for my MongoDB backend, but you might be using PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: @ESV Problem in mocking db here, is that we don't have postgresql database schema described for tornado. BTW we can generate sql from django models and use it in tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the easiest way is just to use a SQL dump for the test database. Create a database, populate it with fixtures, and write it out to file. Simply call `load_fixtures` before you run your tests (or whenever you want to reset the DB). This method can certainly be improved, but it's been good enough for my needs.

```
import os
import unittest2

import tornado.database

settings = dict(
    db_host="127.0.0.1:3306",
    db_name="testdb",
    db_user="testdb",
    db_password="secret",
    db_fixtures_file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'fixtures.sql'),
)

def load_fixtures():
    """Fixtures are stored in an SQL dump.
    """
    os.system("psql %s --user=%s --password=%s < %s" % (settings['db_name'], 
        settings['db_user'], settings['db_password'], settings['db_fixtures_file']))

    return tornado.database.Connection(
        host=settings['db_host'], database=settings['db_name'],
        user=settings['db_user'], password=settings['db_password'])
```